# How can I print integer digits on separate lines using Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I've written code to print the digits of an integer on separate lines, but I am not getting the expected output.  The output of the code is instead in reverse order.  How can I make my output correct without using the `Math.pow` method?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class NumberInDigit
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 
     int div;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter the number");  
     int n = sc.nextInt();
     while(n>0)
     {
         div = n%10;
         n= n/10;
     }
     System.out.println(div); 
   }
}
```

n = 234
Output is 4,3,2
Expected output is 2,3,4

Comment: 234%10 = 4, so 4 gets returned first and so on

Comment: `Output is 4,3,2` ... I don't see any actual code here which would generate any output.

Answer (score 2):

The "%" is the modulo operator so `div = n%10;` takes n (234), then finds the remainder the 234 when divided by 10. 234/10 = 23.4 (i.e. 4 is the remainder). So div is assigned a value of 4 (i.e. div = 4). Then you are dividing n (234), by 10 and reassigning it to n - so (234 / 10 = 23), note the remainder is ignored.

That is the end of the first iteration of the loop, and it returns div = 4.

The second iteration (when n = 23) will print out 3 (because 23 / 10 = 2r3) - remember we are returning the remainders. N is then set to 2.

The third itereration (when n = 2) will print out 2 (because 2/10 = 0r2) - the remainder is 2. N is now set to 0 as (2 / 10 = 0). So then next iteration will fail the condition of n > 0.

This is why you are getting 4,3,2.

There are a number of ways to get the expected number, but since you are working in base10 (i.e. the decimal system), I think the easiest would be just to convert the number into a string and then iterate through the string printing every number until you reached the end, or a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

you are dividing division Remainders and again dividing them again, if you want to operation on string use array

Comment: Because 1st i am taking the remainder and print it , then the number will  divide by 10 because to small the number. For this type of questions Array is to big things

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way also:

```
int n=234,x=n,y=100;
while(x>=0)
    {
        x=n/y;
        n=n%y;
        System.out.println(x);
        y=y/10;
    }
```

This way output is 2,3,4.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code has syntax and logical issues. "n" doesn't have a type and it should only return 4 (since you are executing return it should not continue the while loop).

To accomplish what you need you can change your code a bit:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println(printReversedNumList(234));
}

private static List printReversedNumList(int num) {
    final List<Integer> reversedNumList = new ArrayList<>();
    while(num>0)
    {
        int remainder = num%10;
        num= num/10;
        reversedNumList.add(remainder);
    }

    Collections.reverse(reversedNumList);

    return reversedNumList;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to reverse the number  and don't increase the line of code. n is declared in above code . I had just share the logic why the number output is in reserve order. Just i have to print the number in splited in serial order.